# How to select an s3 profile to use with multer-s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I am uploading files to digital ocean spaces with multer s3 which uses the amazon s3 sdk. I have 2 profiles in my credentials file which is stored in my machine. How can I specify which profile of credentials I want to use in my code? I have found how this can be done using the pure amason s3 sdk but not how to do it with multer s3. This is what my upload code and credentials file look like.

code

```js
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const multer = require("multer");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");
const spaceEndPoint = new aws.Endpoint("ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com");
const s3 = new aws.S3({
 endpoint:spaceEndPoint
})

const upload = multer({
 storage:multerS3({
  s3:s3,
  bucket: "fileRepo",
    contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
  acl:"public-read",
  key:function(request, file, cb){
   console.log(file);
   cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
 })
}).array("upload",1);

router.post("uploadFile", function(req,res){
 upload(req, res, function(error){
  if(error){
   console.log(error);
   return res.redirect("/");
  }
 });
})
```

credentials file

```js
[default] ; default profile
aws_access_key_id = <DEFAULT_ACCESS_KEY_ID>
aws_secret_access_key = <DEFAULT_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
    
[personal-account] ; personal account profile
aws_access_key_id = <PERSONAL_ACCESS_KEY_ID>
aws_secret_access_key = <PERSONAL_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
```

How can I edit the code so that it uses the personal account profile instead of the default profile?

Answer (score 0):

You can also explicitly select the profile used by the AWS Javascript SDK, either by setting process.env.AWS_PROFILE before loading the SDK, or by selecting the credential provider as shown in the following example:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'personal-account'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html